# How to insert object in div using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am making Snake and Ladder game using JavaScript. I want to insert the game board generated from the create Board(dimension) function into a div, but [object Object] is what is appears.

```js
var gameBoard = {
  createBoard: function(dimension) {
    if (!dimension || isNaN(dimension) || !parseInt(dimension, 10)) {
      return false;
    } else {
      dimension = typeof dimension === 'string' ? parseInt(dimension, 10) : dimension;
      var table = document.createElement('table'),
        row = document.createElement('tr'),
        cell = document.createElement('td'),
        rowClone,
        cellClone;
      var output;
      for (var r = 0; r < dimension; r++) {
        rowClone = row.cloneNode(true);
        table.appendChild(rowClone);
        for (var c = 0; c < dimension; c++) {
          cellClone = cell.cloneNode(true);
          rowClone.appendChild(cellClone);
        }
      }
      document.body.appendChild(table);
      output = gameBoard.enumerateBoard(table);
    }
    return output;
  },
  enumerateBoard: function(board) {
    var rows = board.getElementsByTagName('tr'),
      text = document.createTextNode(''),
      rowCounter = 1,
      size = rows.length,
      len,
      cells,
      real,
      odd = false,
      control = 0;
    for (var r = size - 1; r >= 0; r--) {
      cells = rows[r].getElementsByTagName('td');
      len = cells.length;
      rows[r].className = r % 2 == 0 ? 'even' : 'odd';
      odd = ++control % 2 == 0 ? true : false;
      size = rows.length;
      for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        if (odd == true) {
          real = --size + rowCounter - i;
        } else {
          real = rowCounter;
        }
        cells[i].className = i % 2 == 0 ? 'even' : 'odd';
        cells[i].appendChild(text.cloneNode());
        cells[i].firstChild.nodeValue = real;
        rowCounter++;
      }
    }
    return gameBoard;
  }
};
//board.createBoard(10);
document.getElementById("div1").innerHTML = gameBoard.createBoard(10);
```

```css
td {
  border-radius: 10px;
  width: 55px;
  height: 55px;
  line-height: 55px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 0px solid #FFFFFF;
}
table tr:nth-child(odd) td:nth-child(even),
table tr:nth-child(even) td:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: PowderBlue;
}
table tr:nth-child(even) td:nth-child(even),
table tr:nth-child(odd) td:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: SkyBlue;
}
td:hover {
  background: LightCyan !important;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title></title>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <link href="StyleSheet1.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body>
  <div id="div1"></div>
  <script src="JavaScript1.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

I need help on how to solve this problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Gotta say, I hate the idea of using 'div1' as an id for anything. Why not a word that actually identified the div purpose like 'gameBoardSection' or something?  Same thing with all your files, they're all named terribly generically

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I will take it into my considerations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you wanted was the gameBoard to be appended to the div#div1, correct?

- Added `mount` parameter to `createBoard()` function
- `var mount` is a selector that will be referenced as the element to which the `table` element will be appended to.
- Comments accompany changes in the code.
- I added a border around `#div1` to show that the `gameBoard` has been successfully appended to `#div1`

```js
var gameBoard = { //===============▼---▼====[This is can be any selector]
  createBoard: function(dimension, mount) {
    //==▼------------------------------------▼====[Object mount]  
    var mount = document.querySelector(mount);
    if (!dimension || isNaN(dimension) || !parseInt(dimension, 10)) {
      return false;
    } else {
      dimension = typeof dimension === 'string' ? parseInt(dimension, 10) : dimension;
      var table = document.createElement('table'),
        row = document.createElement('tr'),
        cell = document.createElement('td'),
        rowClone,
        cellClone;
      var output;
      for (var r = 0; r < dimension; r++) {
        rowClone = row.cloneNode(true);
        table.appendChild(rowClone);
        for (var c = 0; c < dimension; c++) {
          cellClone = cell.cloneNode(true);
          rowClone.appendChild(cellClone);
        }
      }
      //▼---------------------▼====[Object table append to Object mount] 
      mount.appendChild(table);
      output = gameBoard.enumerateBoard(table);
    }
    return output;
  },
  enumerateBoard: function(board) {
    var rows = board.getElementsByTagName('tr'),
      text = document.createTextNode(''),
      rowCounter = 1,
      size = rows.length,
      len,
      cells,
      real,
      odd = false,
      control = 0;
    for (var r = size - 1; r >= 0; r--) {
      cells = rows[r].getElementsByTagName('td');
      len = cells.length;
      rows[r].className = r % 2 == 0 ? 'even' : 'odd';
      odd = ++control % 2 == 0 ? true : false;
      size = rows.length;
      for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        if (odd == true) {
          real = --size + rowCounter - i;
        } else {
          real = rowCounter;
        }
        cells[i].className = i % 2 == 0 ? 'even' : 'odd';
        cells[i].appendChild(text.cloneNode());
        cells[i].firstChild.nodeValue = real;
        rowCounter++;
      }
    }
    return gameBoard;
  }
};
/*board.createBoard(10);
[On window load call createBoard with 10 rows and mount it to #div1]
▼----------------------------▼===============================*/
window.onload = (function(e) {
  gameBoard.createBoard(10, '#div1');
});
```

```css
td {
  border-radius: 10px;
  width: 55px;
  height: 55px;
  line-height: 55px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 0px solid #FFFFFF;
}
table tr:nth-child(odd) td:nth-child(even),
table tr:nth-child(even) td:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: PowderBlue;
}
table tr:nth-child(even) td:nth-child(even),
table tr:nth-child(odd) td:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: SkyBlue;
}
td:hover {
  background: LightCyan !important;
  cursor: pointer;
}
#div1 {
  border: 3px inset #0FF; 
  border-radius: 10px;
  width: -moz-fit-content;
  width: -webkit-fit-content;
  width: fit-content;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title></title>

</head>

<body>
  <div id="div1"></div>

</body>

</html>
```